# Connections on vector bundles: how they allow us to differentiate sections and to identify fibers?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, connections

A connection $\nabla$ in a vector bundle $E$ over manifold $M$ is a (globally defined) map
$$
\nabla : \Gamma(E) \to \Gamma(T^* M) \otimes \Gamma(E)
$$
that satisfies the Leibniz rule:
$$
\nabla(f \, s) = \mathrm{d}f \otimes s + f \nabla s
$$

I often heard that in vector bundles, a connection gives us a way to identify nearby fibers, so we can differentiate sections, however I don't how this works using the above  definition. Could any one please explain how a connection allows us to identify nearby fibers and to differentiate section ?

Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Kajelad, thank you for the link, that was useful, but I'm not sure how to do this in general for a vector bundle which is not a tangent bundle ?

Comment: @Kajelad, I've understand from your answer to the post in the link, that connection allows us to differentiate  only vector fields wich are defined along a chosen path, not all vectors fields, please correct me if I'm wrong .

Comment: It works in essentially the same way on an arbitrary vector bundle. A connection allows one to differentiate both global vector fields and vector fields along paths. The latter can be defined in terms of the former by working locally and choosing extensions.

Comment: @Kajelad thanks for your comment, I'll try to follow your answer and generalize it to an arbitrary vector bundle. Could you please elaborate more in the second half of your comment: I do understand from your answer how to differentiate a vector field along path but still I don't know how to do it for an arbitrary  vector field ?

Comment: The covariant derivative of a global section $V\in\Gamma(E)$ is just $\nabla V$, which is a $E$-valued one-form. Alternately, one can take the covariant derivative in the direction of a vector field $\nabla_XV$, where $X\in\Gamma(TM)$, by contracting $\nabla V$ with $X$.